# Maximization of a function defined with $\max$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Define the function
$$
f(a,b,c,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,x) = \max\!\bigg(0 , \, \max\!\big( \left(a+x\right)\alpha,\left(b+x\right)\beta \big)  - \left(c+x\right)\gamma\bigg),
$$
where
$$
 a,b,c,\alpha, \beta, \gamma, x \in \left[0, M \right].
$$

Is it true that for any 
$$
\xi = \left( a,b,c,\alpha, \beta, \gamma \right),
$$
the maximum of $f(\xi,\cdot)$ occurs either when $x=0$ or $x=M$?

I think the answer is yes, but I have trouble prooving it.
My argument is as follows:
Given any $\xi$, $f(\xi,c)$ will be
$$
f(\xi,x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{case A} \\
(a+x)\alpha - (c+x)\gamma & \text{case B}\\
(b+x)\beta - (c+x)\gamma & \text{case C}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Hence, $f(\xi,x)$ is a linear function of $x$ in all three cases,
and the result follows.
I think this argument works only if each case is independent of $x$, 
but this is not the case.
As, when $\xi$ is given, judiciously choosing $x$ may put $f$ in another case.

What would be a right way to prove this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that $f$ is a concatenation of convex functions (namely "max" and linear operations), and therefore $f$ is convex.  It follows that one of the end points will always be maximal.